# vectorizing a "leaky integrator" in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I need a leaky integrator -- an IIR filter -- that implements:

```
y[i] = x[i] + y[i-1] * leakiness
```

The following code works.  However, my x vectors are long and this is in an inner loop.  So my questions:

- For efficiency, is there a way to vectorize this in numpy?
- If not numpy, would it be advantageous to use one of the scipy.signal filter algorithms?

The iterative code follows.  `state` is simply the value of the previous y[i-1] that gets carried forward over successive calls:

```py
import numpy as np

def leaky_integrator(x, state, leakiness):
    y = np.zeros(len(x), dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if i == 0:
            y[i] = x[i] + state * leakiness
        else:
            y[i] = x[i] + y[i-1] * leakiness
    return y, y[-1]

>>> leakiness = 0.5
>>> a1 = [1, 0, 0, 0]
>>> state = 0
>>> print("a1=", a1, "state=", state)
a1= [1, 0, 0, 0] state= 0
>>> a2, state = leaky_integrator(a1, state, leakiness)
>>> print("a2=", a2, "state=", state)
a2= [1.    0.5   0.25  0.125] state= 0.125
>>> a3, state = leaky_integrator(a2, state, leakiness)
>>> print("a3=", a3, "state=", state)
a3= [1.0625    1.03125   0.765625  0.5078125] state= 0.5078125
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current answer did not address this:

> If not numpy, would it be advantageous to use one of the scipy.signal filter algorithms?

Yes, scipy.signal is well suited for IIR filtering through [`lfilter()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html#scipy.signal.lfilter), which is [adequately vectorized](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/4d790c14456f72ef7a56aafa0dcc728e5bba22fe/scipy/signal/_lfilter.c.in). It takes input state and returns an `output, output_state` tuple as well, so for this particular case it would be:

```
from scipy.signal import lfilter

def leaky_integrator(x, state, leakiness):
    return lfilter([1], [1, -leakiness], x, zi=state)
```

Except that `lfilter()` expresses `state` (both when accepting and returning it) in a different way than your function. In this case, where your function would accept/return `value`, this function has `[value*leakiness]` (i.e. value is inside a 1-length array, and scaled by `leakiness`). See [`lfilter_zi()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter_zi.html#scipy.signal.lfilter_zi) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

I can see two options:

- The simplest (and suggested solution) is to extend the dependency list and use [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/).
- Use matrix multiplication by rethinking the problem in term of matrix operations.

In fact if `x=[a, b, c]`, `s=state`, `l=leakiness`
then

```
y = [a + s*l, b + (a + s*l)*l, c + (b + (a + s*l)*l)*l]
  = [a + s*l, b + a*l + s*l**2, c + b*l + a*l**2 + s*l**3]
  = [[1, 0, 0], [l, 1, 0], [l**2, l, 1]] @ x + s * [l, l**2, l**3]
```

However you may need to generate a matrix of size `x.size**2` and may get an out of memory error even for small sizes (e.g. for a 1M size array it results about 7 TiB, which I don't think it is doable).

Going back to the numba implemenation, it can be enough to add a `@jit(nopython=True)` decorator to the function you already implemented.

Doing so in my machine with a random array of size 1M:

```py
%timeit leaky_integrator(a1, s, l)
2.07 s ± 99.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit leaky_integrator_jitted(a1, s, l)
7.66 ms ± 22.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

(Remark on numba performance [here](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/5minguide.html#how-to-measure-the-performance-of-numba))

```py
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def leaky_integrator_jitted(x, state, leakiness):
    y = np.zeros(len(x), dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if i == 0:
            y[i] = x[i] + state * leakiness
        else:
            y[i] = x[i] + y[i-1] * leakiness
    return y, y[-1]
```

Comment: Even with the remark on the timings, I find the speed staggering. Something must surely be missing?

Comment: @roganjosh I know timing tools can vary a lot. I am using jupyterlab magic %timeit comand. Trying again I get same order on the original function (2.44 s ± 19.6 ms) but slower on the jitted one (7.66 ms ± 22.2 µs), which is still a 300x on the original function on a 1M size random array

Comment: `ms` I can believe but 600 `ns` for 1 mil entries? :O

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I was just setting it up for a similar speed test with IPython magic in Spyder. My comment wasn't to suggest that the approach was wrong but something surely went wonky in how that `%timeit` worked... just not sure what

Comment: I am updating the answer with this reasonable performances :)
Thank you